# Need feedback for a anglar 8 simple calendar appplication with the abilily to show to dos

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I just built a simple calendar app using angular 8. I would like to get some suggestions for improvements in the project. any feedback will be appreciated. I would like to know what I could have done better in the application in terms of both typescript code and overall app design. this is the github link for my project https://github.com/SagarMajumdar/calapparepo

This is a custom calendar and i am using a JSON structure similar to this to show the calendar as well as the to do items for each day 
[image]
calendar application screenshot
[image]

the way calendar JSON is being contructed is as follows . The subscription is for when a new month and year is selected.

```
  for (let i = 1; i <= this.modays[this.yrmo.mo - 1].days; i++) {
        if (flg === 1) {
          this.dayStructure.days.push (
            {cols: [
              {
                day : i,
                dayname: this.weekdays[(new Date(this.yrmo.yr, this.yrmo.mo - 1, i - 1) ).getDay()].day,
                dayofweek :  (new Date(this.yrmo.yr, this.yrmo.mo - 1, i - 1) ).getDay() + 1
                , todos : this.getotodos(this.yrmo.yr, this.yrmo.mo, i)
              }
            ]} );
          flg = 0;
          this.flagGotMoTodos = true;
        } else {
          this.dayStructure.days[rownum].cols.push(
            {
              day : i,
              dayname: this.weekdays[(new Date(this.yrmo.yr, this.yrmo.mo - 1, i - 1) ).getDay()].day,
              dayofweek :  (new Date(this.yrmo.yr, this.yrmo.mo - 1, i - 1) ).getDay() + 1
              , todos : this.getotodos(this.yrmo.yr, this.yrmo.mo, i)
            }
          );
        }
        if ( (new Date(this.yrmo.yr, this.yrmo.mo - 1, i - 1) ).getDay() === 6 ) {
          flg = 1;
          rownum = rownum + 1;
        }
      }

      console.log('\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n');
      this.dayStructure = this.fillblanks(this.dayStructure);
```

thanks

Comment: I don't understand the schema of your json object. It has a field `days`, which has only 5 items. And why does each day have an array of columns? The days *are* the columns in the calendar. And then the inner-most structure, again has a day field. But you have an object where `day = 1` and `dayname = 'Fri'`, but how is then the next day `Mon` instead of `Sat`?

Comment: The 5 cols of days field is for the 5 rows in the calendar for the month for which this JSON structure is taken

Comment: i am checking the json structure for some possible issues. although not every property in each item of _cols_ is utilized , but there seems to be some issue with the unused properties.

Comment: @JAD I have made a few changes to the post. I put the new JSON structure . There was a bug earlier.